# Explain this Dict comprehension python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
dict1={"a":4,"b":2,"A":6}
print({k.lower():dict1.get(k.lower(),0) + dict1.get(k.upper(),0) for k in dict1.keys()})
```

I copied this code from a youtube video. I couldn't understand the code properly. Please help me to figure it out.
I couldn't understand the purpose of **0** in second line.

```
k.lower():dict1.get(k.lower(),0)
```

I'm a beginner in python. kindly help me

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: To return 0 if that key doesn't exist (instead of throwing KeyError)

Comment: just do `for k in dict1`

Comment: i want to add the value of key(a) and key(A)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the value parameter, that is , if the key does not exist this will be the value.
In your example, dict1["B"] does not exist. Normally that would cause an error. But because the value parameter is 0, instead of causing an error it pretends that dict1["B"] is 0. Note that this does not change the original dictionary.\

Comment: but  ```dict1.get(k.lower()) ``` exist and when i remove 0 ... it throws error .? why?

Comment: but k.upper() does not exist for "b"